# How do I generate a Python timestamp to my format?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can i generate a timestamp in python to this format? '2023-03-24T12:02:20.1273789+01:00'

```
formatted_timestamp = datetime.strptime(timestamp_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z').strftime(
                '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

this returns

```
error: time data '2023-03-24T12:02:20.1273789+01:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem with this `timestamp_string` is the number of microseconds digits - datetime expects it to be no more that 6.

To solve this, you can use [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/)

```
from dateutil import parser

s = "2023-03-24T12:02:20.1273789+01:00"
res = parser.parse(s)
formatted_timestamp = res.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Or format a bit earlier your `timestamp_string`:

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

timestamp_string = "2023-03-24T12:02:20.1273789+01:00"
clean_timestamp = re.sub(r"\d\+", "+", timestamp_string)

formatted_timestamp = datetime.strptime(clean_timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: great, Thanks! 

The second part worked.